# Duplicate of deleted question

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, duplicates

I recently came across [a duplicate question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53866/difference-between-validation-and-verification). However, [the question it a a duplicate of](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42893/verification-and-validation-difference) is deleted. What is the right thing to do in this case? Should I flag the the duplicate for unduplication? Should I just leave it alone?

Comment: I've voted to reopen the question, despite not being sure what the procedure is, in cases like these. It seems the most logical one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I undeleted the original, which had been deleted by an automatic process, but then realized that it had been closed as a gen ref question. So I redeleted it and reopened the other instead (un-duplicated it).

It is a good idea to flag these with a custom flag and tell us that the linked duplicate has been deleted. This kind of thing happens sometimes, where an auto-delete occurs, and we don't know that it has been linked to something. We're not likely to notice unless someone flags it.

It is a good idea to flag posts that have dead links as well, again with a custom flag that mentions that the link is dead. This is sort of a special case of that.

Thanks for asking, and thanks for helping.